# OptionMenu not working when using overridedirect on two different windows

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python 3.6 on a mac, in view of creating controls for a heating system using a Raspberry Pi 3. I have created a master Tk window with a canvas in it to display graphics for on/off times. I am using an OptionMenu in a top-level popup window with overridedirect to remove the window decorations. I wish to also use overridedirect on the master Tk window, but when I use these two instances of overridedirect, my OptionMenu ceases to work(it works with just one use of overridedirect). The OptionMenu is displayed in the popup window, but does not drop down when clicked on. It is quite a long program, so I haven't included any of my code as I'm unsure what would be relevant. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Didn't think I could do it, which is why I didn't include code(kept getting errors), but managed it in the end!

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

master.overrideredirect(1) # remove window border

master.geometry('800x480')

canvas_window = Canvas(master, width=800, height=305)

outer_rect = canvas_window.create_rectangle(39, 3, 760, 304, fill="BLUE")

close_button = Button(master, text="close", command=master.destroy)
close_button.pack()

def menu_sel_trg(self): 
    print("Menu Triggered")

def popup(*self):
    popup_win = Toplevel()
    popup_win.wm_overrideredirect(1)  # remove window border
    popup_win.geometry('250x250')
    on_hrs_options = range(0, 24, 1)# sets range of list
    on_hrs_variable = StringVar(popup_win) 
    on_hrs_variable.set(1)# menu default value
    menu_on_hours = OptionMenu(popup_win, on_hrs_variable, *on_hrs_options, command=menu_sel_trg) 
    menu_on_hours.pack()
    close_popup = Button(popup_win, text="Close", command=popup_win.destroy)
    close_popup.pack()

canvas_window.tag_bind(outer_rect, '<Button-1>', popup)

canvas_window.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We will probably need some code to help you. See [mcve], [no mcve](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) and [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/) to help you choose what code to post.

Comment: I tried it again on my Pi 3 and it seems to work ok. Unsure why, no doubt my mistake. It still does not work correctly when run on my mac in Idle 3, but that is of no consequence now as it works ok on the Pi.